# Ignore 2nd delimiter in a same line

Tags: java, string, split

How do I ignore the second occurrence of delimiter in a same line while splitting in java?

Let's say this is one of the line in csv file:

```
This is key, This is, value
```

In the above scenario I want to split line by comma and get a value as

```
<column 1>This is key <column 2> This is, value
```

How do I ignore the second comma while doing `line.split(",")`?

Comment: Please provide your code so far :)

Comment: Get a CSV parser library. If a field has a comma, it needs to be quoted. If that's not the case, talk to the people that provide the data.

Comment: Do you need to ignore _all commas_ except the first one? Or all the input data contain just three columns?

Comment: @AlexRudenko As of now, i am only seeing 2nd occurrence of delimiter in a same line. But it would be better to use the first delimiter and ignore the rest after the first.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with an overloaded version of `split`:

```
String value = "This is key, This is, value";
String[] splitter = value.split(",", 2);
```

Running this in JShell:

```
jshell> String value = "This is key, This is, value";
   ...> String[] splitter = value.split(",", 2);
value ==> "This is key, This is, value"
splitter ==> String[2] { "This is key", " This is, value" }
```

The second parameters controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.

Probably you want to apply a `trim()` on the result strings. But the best idea is really to have a CSV parser if you want to process CSV files here.